# Does flutter_background_geolocation fetch the location even when app is killed?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, location

I’ve been using [background_locator](https://pub.dev/packages/background_locator) to fetch the location of the user in the background even when app is killed. To be honest, it’s the only package that worked for me. Now this package is not reliable after using for months and the maintainer doesn’t publish updates often.

I’m look for alternative. Is [flutter_background_geolocation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_geolocation) a true alternative?

Comment: Facing few issues in working with background_locator. Can you provide me with a working example for tracking background location which you're using!?

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72246232/issue-while-using-background-locator-plugin-while-tracking-background-location-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m the author of this plugin.

Yes, if you configure `stopOnTerminate: true`.

*Android Headless Mode* (`enableHeadless: true`) is optional, required only if you have custom business logic.  The SDK’s built-in http service can automatically upload each recorded location to your server *without* a headless-task.

iOS will resume tracking after the device moves ~200 meters beyond last known location, when the OS automatically re-launches your app in the background, just as if launched from the home screen.

Have a look at the API docs linked at the top of the [GitHub repo README](https://github.com/transistorsoft/flutter_background_geolocation), they’ quite extensive.

Comment: How do I send the data periodically to the socket using HTTP method?

Comment: @SheetalGhori, found an answer?

Comment: Not yet, As of now I set a timer.periodic while app is terminated @KizatSuleimenov

Comment: Please explain the package behavior for iOS when app is terminated. I need my application to track user location on iOS even when app is closed. I have headless task registered on main. However, I know that headless mode works only for android.I do have a home screen with all functions onLocation, onProvider, etc. I am not sure how will the location of the user for iOS would still be tracked even when app is killed/ closed as all of the logic for this resides in the home screen.

Answer (score 1):

It does work even when the app is terminated. it is called headless mode in android. I have tested in android and seems to work so far.

[Android Headless Mode Flutter Background Geolocation](https://github.com/transistorsoft/flutter_background_geolocation/wiki/Android-Headless-Mode)

I havent't tested in iOS yet.

Comment: it provides a pretty good documentation